# Compact data structure for storing a large set of integral values

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I'm working on an application that needs to pass around large sets of `Int32` values.  The sets are expected to contain `~1,000,000-50,000,000` items, where each item is a database key in the range `0-50,000,000`.  I expect distribution of ids in any given set to be effectively random over this range.  The operations I need on the set are dirt simple:

- Add a new value
- Iterate over all of the values.

There is a serious concern about the memory usage of these sets, so I'm looking for a data structure that can store the ids more efficiently than a simple `List<int>`or `HashSet<int>`.  I've looked at `BitArray`, but that can be wasteful depending on how sparse the ids are.  I've also considered a bitwise `trie`, but I'm unsure how to calculate the space efficiency of that solution for the expected data.  A Bloom Filter would be great, if only I could tolerate the false negatives.

I would appreciate any suggestions of data structures suitable for this purpose.  I'm interested in both out-of-the-box and custom solutions.

**EDIT**: To answer your questions:

- No, the items don't need to be sorted
- By "pass around" I mean both pass between methods *and* serialize and send over the wire.  I clearly should have mentioned this.
- There could be a decent number of these sets in memory at once (~100).

Comment: 50 million 4-byte items means 200 megabytes; is that really too much in this day and age? :)

Comment: Are you looking for better than O(1) insert and O(n) to iterate all values?  Sounds like `LinkedList<T>` is what you want.

Comment: "serialize and send over the wire" sounds like optimizing access time for manipulating these things in memory hardly matters any more :) what on earth are you doing??

Comment: Even at the lower end (10^6 items), a bitset is less than 50% larger than a simple array of 32 bit integers (6MB vs 3.8MB), which is the most compact explicit representation you can get. I think bitsets are a shoo-in here.

Comment: Had another thought, you could use a very simple compression scheme on a bitset which would dramatically reduce the size for smaller values of n, and have an impact of at most about 12% in the worst case. Use the first bit of each byte to encode skips, e.g. 0 means treat the next 7 bits normally, 1 means skip the next n values where the next 7 bits are n. Would speed up iteration a lot for smaller values of n as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `BitArray`. It uses only some 6MB of memory; the only real problem is that iteration is Theta(*N*), i.e. you have to walk the entire range. Locality of reference is good though and you can allocate the entire structure in one operation.

As for wasting space: you waste 6MB in the worst case.

**EDIT**: ok, you've lots of sets and you're serializing. For serializing on disk, I suggest 6MB files :)

For sending over the wire, just iterate and consider sending **ranges** instead of individual elements. That does require a sorting structure.

You need lots of these sets. Consider if you have 600MB to spare. Otherwise, check out:

- Bytewise tries: O(1) insert, O(*n*) iteration, much lower constant factors than bitwise tries
- A custom hash table, perhaps [Google sparsehash](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/) through C++/CLI
- BSTs storing ranges/intervals
- [Supernode BSTs](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/papers/super.pdf)

Comment: +1. I'm interested in the breakpoint for access time. You only need access one byte to iterate over 8 numbers compared to long form. Getting each # that is part of a given byte from a given starting point can probably be done very fast with bitwise operators. I wonder how the math works out, would the breakpoint be somewhere around 1/32 (1.5 million records) for iterating through a fully loaded set? e.g. it would have to be below 1.5 mil for a bitset to be slower. Or am I not thinking through everything involved in the iteration process.

Comment: Iteration may skip over blocks of *k* all-zero bits, where *k* is likely 8, 16, 32 or 64. The denser the set becomes, the slower it gets, esp. if the values are uniformly distributed.

Comment: 32 times better than the naive implementation...not bad, sir!

Comment: The OP already suggested it. I just doubt anything would beat this representation, including my earlier suggestion, given that the number of items may get close to the full range and a bitset has close to 0 overhead.

Comment: "The denser the set becomes, the slower it gets" - I wasn't even thinking about skipping. Even considering this, it seems like it would compensated for in some part by the fact that your memory accesses are 1/32 compared to an int list. otoh, there's a math operation needed to return each number.

Comment: "iteration is Theta(n)" - which may not even be such a big deal. The bitset is always at least 2% full, so the difference between iteration being proportional to number of elements in the set, vs proportional to the entire range, is a factor of 50 rather than a different complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer depends on what you mean by "passing around" and what you're trying to accomplish. You say you are only adding to the list: how often do you add? How fast will the list grow? What is an acceptable overhead for memory use, versus the time to reallocate memory?

In your worst case, 50,000,000 32-bit numbers = 200 megabytes using the most efficient possible data storage mechanism. Assuming you may end up with this much use in your worst case scenario, is it OK to use this much memory all the time? Is that better than having to reallocate memory frequently? What's the distribution of typical usage patterns? You could always just use an `int[]` that's pre-allocated to the whole 50 million.

As far as access speed for your operations, nothing is faster than iterating and adding to a pre-allocated chunk of memory.

From OP edit: **There could be a decent number of these sets in memory at once (~100).**

Hey now. You need to store 100 sets of 1 to 50 million numbers in memory at once? I think the bitset method is the only possible way this could work.

That would be 600 megabytes. Not insignificant, but unless they are (typically) mostly empty, it seems *very* unlikely that you would find a more efficient storage mechanism.

Now, if you don't use bitsets, but rather use dynamically sized constructs, and they could somehow take up less space to begin with, you're talking about a real ugly memory allocation/deallocation/garbage collection scenario.

Let's assume you *really* need to do this, though I can only imagine why. So your server's got a ton of memory, just allocate as many of these 6 megabyte bitsets as you need and recycle them. Allocation and garbage collection are no longer a problem. Yeah, you're using a ton of memory, but that seems inevitable.

Comment: A bitset would only require 6MB, at the expense of Theta(n) iteration.

Comment: How do you store 50 million distinct 32 bit numbers in 6.25 megabytes?

Comment: Allocate 50 million bits = 6MB, initialize to 0, set element `i` to 1 to insert `i`. But the OP found this solution wasteful.

Comment: I don't see where the 50mill bits comes from when the OP says 50mill 32-bit values?

Comment: "where each item is a database key in the range 0-50,000,000" (so actually 500.00.001 bits)

Comment: To store 50,000,000, you need around 28 bits?  And the OP states they want 1 - 50 million of those...

Comment: You don't explicitly store the numbers in a bitset. You set the bit at index `i` to 1 to indicate that `i` is a member of the set.

Comment: Oh I see, flag the bit and the index is the database key?

Comment: Oh, I see, but that depends on the values being unique, which I guess they are if they are database keys. Basically in index. I like it. If the *order* is not important then this makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Yep. The OP is talking about sets, so the values are unique. Your solution is *very* wasteful compared to this setup, though it might be faster.

Comment: I wouldn't have deleted your own answer there then mate, addresses the serious concerns over memory directly.  Not sure how straight forward it would be to iterate over bits though - sticking a load of ints into BitVectors doesn't sound fun.

Comment: I think he meant *"sets"* as in *"groups"*, not mathematical sets.

Comment: I concur. I think whether it's a better solution or not depends entirely on the likely distribution of values. If there were going to be under a couple million records most of the time, using a regular integer construct would likely make more sense. If there was a relatively even distribution of the # of values from 0-50 mil, then a bitset would almost certainly be faster on average. When you also consider memory allocation time, and the fact that iterating over 32 bit numbers means accessing four bytes per iteration rather than one (for every 8 iterations), it seems a no brainer.

Comment: @BlueRaja: then the `HashSet`, the trie and the Bloom filter the OP mentions wouldn't be valid options.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the distribution of the sizes of your sets. Unless you expect *most* of the sets to be (close to) the minimum you've specified, I'd probably use a bitset. To cover a range up to 50,000,000, a bitset ends up ~6 megabytes.

Compared to storing the numbers directly, this is marginally larger for the minimum size set you've specified (~6 megabytes instead of ~4), but considerably smaller for the maximum size set (1/32<sup>nd</sup> the size).

The second possibility would be to use a delta encoding. For example, instead of storing each number directly, store the difference between that number and the previous number that was included. Given a maximum magnitude of 50,000,000 and a minimum size of 1,000,000 items, the average difference between one number and the next is ~50. This means you can theoretically store the difference in <6 bits on average. I'd probably use the 7 least significant bits directly, and if you need to encode a larger gap, set the msb and (for example) store the size of the gap in the lower 7 bits plus the next three bytes. That can't happen *very* often, so in most cases you're using only one byte per number, for about 4:1 compression compared to storing numbers directly. In the best case this would use ~1 megabyte for a set, and in the worst about 50 megabytes -- 4:1 compression compared to storing numbers directly.

If you don't mind a little bit of extra code, you could use an adaptive scheme -- delta encoding for small sets (up to 6,000,000 numbers), and a bitmap for larger sets.

Comment: "This means you can theoretically store the difference in <6 bits on average" - although wouldn't adding a value then be pretty heavyweight, since it's basically inserting into the middle of an array. I suppose you could tack a large negative delta on the end cheaply. The problem then is detecting duplicates, but the same is true of adding to a `List<int>`, which the questioner seems happy with functionally, just not happy with storage efficiency.